# How to include external jar in library project output classes.jar

Tags: android, android-studio, library-project

I am creating a library project and including a jar in this library project. Android Studio compiles it and create an **AAR** file. This **AAR** file includes libs folder having that external jar and `classes.jar` of project. But I want a single `classes.jar` having that external jar inside it. Please suggest

Comment: place your jar file in Yourproject/app/lib/yourlib.jar, Now add it by going project settings + button -> External library-> choose your jar

Comment: Hi Satish. I know how to add a jar in project. My question is -  it creates an AAR file which have both classes.jar and all external jars in libs folder. But I want a single output jar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used proguard and **proguard** merged the libs/jars in **classes.jar**

Comment: Hello, I have the same need as you but I do not know how to set build.gradle to generate classes.jar with the jar dependencies inside. Thanks a lot

Comment: Maybe it's already out of date, but how do you used proguard to merge the external jars into the classes.jar?